# Iptables to forward HTTPS traffic to remote HTTPS proxy

Tags: networking, proxy, port, iptables, ssl

My goal is to use Iptables to take all traffic going to my server on port 443 and forward it to a remote HTTPS proxy server.

So basically if I was to use my ip of 192.168.1.142:443 as a SSL proxy it will actually be using the remote server over at X.X.X.X:8080

```
sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to X.X.X.X:8080
```

Did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Turns out, Iptables was the wrong way to go about this. I used Haproxy and setup a backend that talks to that proxy server.